# How to write this function in ES6 fat arrow?

Tags: javascript, passport.js

I want to rewrite this function in to ES6 fat arrow, but not sure how?

```
    passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
        res.redirect("/secret");
     });
```

I thought this might be the way but nope:

```
    passport.authenticate("local")((req, res)=>{
        res.redirect("/secret");
     });
```

Comment: Why do you think the arrow function should have different parameters from the original function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, () => {
        res.redirect("/secret");
     });
```

It can be done this way.

Comment: Yeah, this fixes the issue, looks like OP inadvertently changed the function signature. This answer fixes that.


Correct solution: passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, anonymous_function)

OPs fat arrow soluction: passport.authenticate("local")(anonymous_function)

Comment: Ah yes of course! I feel kinda stupid now.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you are not planning on doing anything else in the arrow function then you could do it like this.

```
passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, () => res.redirect("/secret"));
```